# Adding an "id" attribute to a Datatable row

Tags: datatables

Here's a trimmed down code-fragment where I add a new row to my table and then attempt to add the id attribute to the resultant " tr " so the row can be located later. Maybe the row hasn't been rendered yet when I attempt to add the attribute? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
test = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

node = $('#MyDataTable').DataTable().row.add( test );

// this doesn't seem to work - need to end up with: "<tr id='MyUniqueID'>"
node.to$().attr('id', 'MyUniqueID' );
```

Comment: I don't understand ... your problem is: "Add the `id` to each row" or "get the `id` from each row"?

Comment: I'm trying to add the id. My assumption is that the attr call sets the attribute. Bad assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Jquery DataTables, data is usually added with `fnAddData()`, which returns an index (or multiple indexes if more than one row is inserted) of the row that it just added. You can use that index to locate the row with `fnGetNodes()`

```
test = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var rowIndex = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnAddData(test);
var row = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnGetNodes(rowIndex);
$(row).attr( 'id', 'MyUniqueID' );
```

Comment: I should have noted that I'm trying to get this working using the new 1.10 APIs, using $().DataTable() instead of $().dataTable(). But since your solution works, and I can mix and match old and new APIs, I'll mark the solution as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use "createRow" callback like this one:

```
$("#your-id").DataTable({
    // Define custom handler for createdRow event
    "createdRow" : function( row, data, index ) {

        // Add identity if it specified
        if( data.hasOwnProperty("id") ) {
            row.id = "row-" + data.id;
        }       
    }
});

// Add some data
var data = ["col-1","col-2","col-3","col-4"];

// Arrays are objects in javascript, so you can add custom properties to your array and read them in createdRow callback
data.id = "your-id";

// Create row in ordinary way
$("#your-id").row.add(data)
    .draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add attributes for rows after the table rendered using `fnRowCallback`

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
          if(aData[0] == "A"){
                $(nRow).attr( 'data-blah',"modal" );
                $(nRow).attr( 'style',"display:none" );
          }
    }
```

For more details about [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback)

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AravindhGopi/29uL7tqe/)